# How to install FlashPlayer 23 (PPAPI)?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, flash, 16.10, tar

The file that I get from the [official Adobe website](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) is in the tar.gz file format.  I tried the "standard" way of installing software with that extension, which wouldn't work.

Also, installing using Canonical's repo gives me version 11.2, which is very outdated.

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't install it. Most websites support HTML5 now. Also, Google Chrome's Pepperflash can work for most flash-only sites. Only install Flash Player if you really need it.

Comment: @AaronFranke The adobe-flashplugin package installs the PPAPI (pepper) plug-in for use in Chromium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to install the `adobe-flashplugin` package from the *Partner* repository.

Note that the version shown in chrome://plugins will still be 11.2.999.999 and not 23. This is also true if you download the file from the page linked to in your question and place the *libpepflashplayer.so* file in the system folder.

However, if you visit https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ it should show that you have version 23.

Answer (score 4):

Canonical's repo currently installs version 11 of the NPAPI plugin and version 23 of the PPAPI plugin, so no, the PPAPI it installs is not outdated at all. (Soon it will start to install an updated version of NPAPI as well.)

Accordingly, all you need to do is enabling [Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and installing the `adobe-flashplugin` package.

```
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Where did you get this info that it will have an updated NPAPI version of flash?

Comment: @dobey: [Here](https://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/08/beta-news-flash-player-npapi-for-linux.html#sthash.3X3ZPVZP.kPbmTGtq.dpbs). I [make the beta of it available in a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/adobe-flashplugin).

Comment: Thanks, though I still think my answer is more appropriate for the question, as it is clearly stated in the question that there is confusion about the version number, which you do not address here, and otherwise basically say the same as my answer, to use the official package.

Comment: @dobey: Possibly. But we don't know that the OP is talking about Chrome/Chromium; I'd guess that he uses Firefox, and that it's the version of NPAPI he sees in the browser.

Comment: Well, given that the question specifically mentions PPAPI, and that is only usable in Chromium based browser, I would contend that is what is being asked about, unless the question is "how do I use pepper in Firefox" in which case, nothing here is relevant either. Even in Chromium, with PPAPI, the local plugins list shows it as 11.2, which is incorrect (and likely a bug in Chrom{e,ium}.

Comment: @dobey: Indeed; let's await the OP response.

Answer (score 0):

**ADOBE BEGINS TO SUPPORT LINUX IN EXPERIMENTAL WAY**

I managed it to work in the following way.

Create a directory in your user directory like `pepper`

```
 mkdir ~/pepper
```

go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

in the first step pick up Linux32 or Linux64 (according to your installation achitecture)

in the second step in dropdown list; pick up `FP 23.0 for other Linux ..`

download the archive,
and extract contents of tar.gz into `~/pepper`

and run your chromium from terminal

```
 /usr/bin/chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=${HOME}/pepper/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=`grep -i version ${HOME}/pepper/manifest.json | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Considering that the `adobe-flashplugin` package exists, the above advice isn't very helpful.