# Adobe Flash installation problem in Xubuntu 16.04.1 i386

Tags: xubuntu, flash

This question and answer may be applicable to other Ubuntu distros.

After I installed Xubuntu 16.04.1 on my i386 laptop I noticed that I soon got a notice from the updater that the Adobe Flashplayer could not be found. I also looked at Firefox and when I visited a game on Facebook that I play with my spouse I could see that Firefox requires flash because I was prompted to have it installed.

I searched for the Adobe Flashplayer in the Xubuntu software but I was unable to find it.

Comment: Can you please write the answer part of your post as a separate post below? Writing a Q&A is fine but you do need to separate the Q from the A.

Comment: Did you try open a terminal and type: sudo apt install flashplugin-installer?

Comment: try manual installation here http://askubuntu.com/questions/852725/how-to-install-flashplayer-23-ppapi/852732#852732

Answer (score 3):

You can install Flash by [enabling Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work in Xubuntu. That is why I had to perform a manual installation. I also attempted to update the repository and that didn't work either.

Comment: It works for everyone else. You could ask why you can't update.

Comment: In order to "work for everyone else" one needs to add the partner repository first.  @Pilot6

Comment: I researched other posts on this subject here and elsewhere on the net. If I had found apt update successful, I wouldn't have tried a different approach.

Answer (score -3):

I visited the following URL https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

This allows one to download an apt/deb, however when I attempted to do so Xubuntu attempts to open this instead of downloading it, and as a result it will fail. How then to download flash and install it?

Where the Adobe web page says select version to download choose ".tar.gz for Linux"

At the above URL we need to download the .tar.gz file instead, because this prompts the user to save the file to the users downloads folder rather than open it. The file is `flash_player_npapi_linux.i386.tar.gz`.

Once this file is in the downloads folder navigate there, this can be done via Firefox downloads menu, click on the blue arrow at the top of the menu then use the folder icon beside the download name to open the folder. After the folder opens at this point you can then close Firefox if you so wish.

Once in the downloads folder the user will be in their file manager. Right click on the icon of `flash_player_npapi_linux.i386.tar.gz` and choose "Extract Here" from the context menu. This will create a folder called `flash_player_npapi_linux.i386`.

Open the folder, inside you will find all the files needed to install the Flashplayer, and importantly a readme.txt file. This file explains how to install the software. The command line is used, but it is not hard to do so. Importantly insofar as Xubuntu is concerned, the location of the Firefox plugin folder isn't given in the instruction so you will need to know what it is. That folder is located at `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins/` in Xubuntu. Its location may be different in other distros. You also have to be root because that folder requires permissions to change it, so all terminal commands will require sudo. Its not hard to do!

The first thing is to copy libflashplayer.so into the plugins folder. In the folder we currently have open "flash_player_npapi_linux.i386" right click somewhere in the window (not on an icon) and from the context menu choose "Open Terminal Here".

When the terminal opens you will see a command line, copy and paste the following into the terminal. Copy it from here, and then right click at the terminal prompt, and choose paste, when the line appears you may then press enter to execute the line. You will be prompted to enter the root password, so you must know what it is.

```
sudo cp libflashlayer.so /usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins/
```

After you enter the root password the file will be copied into the directory.

You must also copy the user settings into the appropriate directory, enter the following command and press enter to execute it. You will not need to enter the root password this time.

```
sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
```

You must then restart Firefox to have it use the plugin.

As soon as I restarted Firefox, returned to Facebook, and navigated to the game I wanted to play with my spouse, I could see that the Flashplayer was working, loaded, and I was able to play it.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: There is no need to do it this way.